# Laravel video upload - issue with ios device, mime-type application/octet-stream

Tags: php, laravel

I created an API to upload videos.

when I upload a video from postman its works fine
but when I use the same API with ios device file extension missing.

**Request from POSTMAN**

```
array (
  'post_id' => '25',
  'file' =>
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'IMG_5190.MOV',
     'mimeType' => 'video/quicktime',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

**Request from IOS**

```
array (
  'post_id' => '5331',
  'file' =>
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'phpKz6dKN',
     'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

**File Upload Code**

```
$file           = $request->file('file');
$ext            = $file->getclientoriginalextension() ? $file->getclientoriginalextension() : 'mov';
$size           = $file->getSize();
$filename       = Str::random(100) . date('his').'.'.$ext;
$localVideo     = Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, file_get_contents($file));
```

So I just added an extension **.mov** if there is none.

someone please guide me to proper way to upload **'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream'** type files.

Answer (score -1):

it is problem in your php.ini file. max_file_size.